# foreach loop inside another foreach loop using Custom PHP MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have a table 1 **products** and Table 2 **suppliers**

The tables structure is this way:

**Products**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
`id_product` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
`id_supplier` int(11) NOT NULL,   
`name_product` varchar(20) NOT NULL,     
PRIMARY KEY (`id_product`) )
ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**Suppliers**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `suppliers` (
`id_supplier` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
`name_supplier` varchar(11) NOT NULL,    
PRIMARY KEY (`id_supplier`) ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Model: (**suppliers_model.php**)

```
class Suppliers_Model extends Model{

    public function fetchSuppliers(){
        stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM suppliers");
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();       
    }
}
```

Controller (**suppliers.php**)

```
class Suppliers extends Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->view->Suppliers= $this->model->fetchSuppliers();
    }
}
```

View :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name of supplier</th>
        <th>List of products</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($this->Suppliers AS $key=>$value):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value->id_supplier; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value->name_supplier; ?></td>
        <td>
                <?php foreach():?>
                    **HERE I Wante To display a liste of products**
                    1. Product A
                    2. Product B
                    etc....
                <?php endforeach;?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

How to created another model and a controller to fetch list of products and pass the value

> $value->id_supplier

as a condition to display the list of products of each supplier?

I've tried this code but it doesn't work

```
    public function listProducts($id_supplier){
        stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id_supplier=$id_supplier");
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll();

    }
```

and added this code to the controller

```
$this->view->listProducts= $this->model->listProducts('id_supplier');
```

and tried to use the foreach loop to loop through the products table to retrieve the list of products but it doesn't work

> NB: Im working with a custom PHP MVC

Comment: $this->model->listProducts('id_supplier'); you are asking literaly for products having 'id_supplier'

Comment: Did your MVC support some view helpers?

Comment: why not use existing framework like CI or something else? anyways, you aren't feeding the actual id but rather a string `id_supplier`. and you should have done that inside the controller. gather all data logic inside the controller, only assign the data and then just present it inside the view, no more model method calling inside the view

Comment: @LukasJahoda Helpers like what? I'm still a beginner in MVC and don't know whats those helpers mean !

Comment: @Ghost it an exam and Im obliged to user my own MVC not any other framework, that's why

Comment: @Ghost Can you please provide me with an example?

Comment: @SpyDer okay, just use the same patern of MVC, logic inside the controller (gather all data and stuff from models), then just present inside the view

Comment: @Ghost , I mean, How? i need and example please :)

Comment: @SpyDer which model does `listProducts` belong anyways? you'll need to load that model inside suppliers controller too

Comment: @Ghost it belongs to the Suppliers_Model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already setup the model method to get the products, just use it in your controller.

Don't try to make invocations inside the views, do it inside the controller.

Controller:

```
public function index()
{

    $suppliers = $this->model->fetchSuppliers();
    foreach($suppliers as &$s) {
        $s->products = $this->model->listProducts($s->id_supplier);
    }

    $this->view->Suppliers = $suppliers; 
}
```

Then in your view, just continue on what you have:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name of supplier</th>
        <th>List of products</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($this->Suppliers AS $key=>$value):?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $value->id_supplier; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value->name_supplier; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php foreach($value->products as $k => $p): ?>
               <p><?php echo ($k + 1) '. ' . $p->product_name; ?></p>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```